# Python time.clock() - reset clock value with threads

Tags: python, time, reset, clock

I see time.clock() on Windows 'starts' a timer when called for the first time, and returns elasped time since the first call for calls after that. I read that the only way to restart the clock is to start a new process.

Is starting and killing threads supposed to restart the time.clock() as well? It doesn't seem to be working right now. If not, is the only solution to re-launch the entire executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thread is not a process, so, no. (As a minor point, you can't kill a thread in Python, you can only ask it to exit. Killing threads through other means, where such means even exist, is likely to leave Python in a bad state.)

The question is *why* you want to reset the timer, and also why you are using `time.clock()`. If you care about the elapsed time between two points at such a high granularity that `time.time()` is not suitable, you'll just have to subtract the first point from the second point. No resetting required. I would recommend just using `time.time()` unless you really care about that tiny bit of difference in granularity, as `time.time()` works the same way on all platforms, contrary to `time.clock()`.

Comment: i'm trying to measure response between serial communications, so yes, i would want to use time.clock(). I'll go ahead and subtract the two values to find the difference. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Leaving threads apart if you want a clock you can reset with the precision of `time.clock()` which is higer than the one of `time.time()` just because the float of the second one is bigger (almost imperceptible difference), for measuring the lapse of time past while running some code you can try this:

```
t0 = time.clock()
... do something
print('Running time:', time.clock()-t0)
```

Yo can also try a function decoration for this:

```
def duration(code):
    def f(*args):
        t0 = time.clock()
        bar = code(*args)
        print('Running time:', time.clock()-t0)
        return bar
    return f
```

After this you can define your function with the decorator:

```
@duration
def myFun(*args):
    ... do something
```

Or just call the function with the decorator:

```
duration(myFun)(*args)
```